# expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am very new to spring and trying to developing one application in spring boot.I know this is duplicate question but I didnt find any solution to my problem..
I have a class called **UserController**  which is like below

```
    @RestController
    public class UserController {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);
        private final UserService userService;

        DatabaseConnections dataconnections = new DatabaseConnections(); 
       @Autowired
       private DAO dao;      
        @Inject
        public UserController(final UserService userService) {
            this.userService = userService;  
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public User createUser(@RequestBody @Valid final User user) {
            LOGGER.debug("Received request to create the {}", user);
            return userService.save(user);
        }
       @RequestMapping(value = "/getuser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public JSONObject getUser(@PathVariable String id) {

    return dao.getUsers(id);
    }
    }
```

I have one more class which is having some function :

```
@Service("dao")
    public class DAO {    
      public JSONObject getUsers(@PathVariable String id) {
                Connection dbConnection = null;
                Statement statement = null;
                JSONObject userJSONObject = new JSONObject();
                String selectusers = "SELECT* from emp;
                try {
                    dbConnection = dataconnections.getPostgresConnection(hostname, port, dbname, username, password);
                    statement = dbConnection.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(selectusers);
                    while (rs.next()) {
                           --
                        ---
                    }
                    return userJSONObject;
    }
```

I want to use the getUsers function in usercontroler class

I am getting error below when I try to do by this way.

```
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userController': Injection of autowired dependencies  
   failed; nested exception is   
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire  
 field: private com.emc.bdma.itaudemo.postgres.dao.DAO   
com.emc.bdma.itaudemo.restclient.controller.UserController.dao; nested   
exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:   
No qualifying bean of type [com.emc.bdma.itaudemo.postgres.dao.DAO] found for  
 dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for    
this dependency. Dependency annotations:   
{@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: You haven't shared enough code to diagnose the problem. Please share you main application class. It'd also help to know which package(s) both it and your `DAO` class are in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just solved the issue...

```
@RestController
    public class UserController {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UserController.class);
        private final UserService userService;
   @Autowired
        DatabaseConnections dataconnections 
       @Autowired
       private DAO dao;      
        @Inject
        public UserController(final UserService userService) {
            this.userService = userService;  
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.POST)
        public User createUser(@RequestBody @Valid final User user) {
            LOGGER.debug("Received request to create the {}", user);
            return userService.save(user);
        }
       @RequestMapping(value = "/getuser/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
       public JSONObject getUser(@PathVariable String id) {

    return dao.getUsers(id);
    }
    }
```

There is a databaseConnection class is instantiating...We have to mark the class as `@Component`

```
@Component
public class DatabaseConnections {

  public Connection getPostgresConnection(String hostname, String port, String dbname, String username, String password)
```

And also declare DAo as `@Component` or service

```
@Service("dao")
@Component
public class DAO {
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems that it has not found yur DAO object. I suggest annotating the DAO with `@Service` annotation like this:

```
@Service("dao")
public class DAO {
}
```

and then injecting it into the class where you are using it with `@Autowired` annotation:

```
@Autowire
private DAO dao;
```

Moreover, you can also autowire an interface in a similar way and then specify which implementation will be used if there are more than one.

If this is not the case, post the full code of the class calling the dao function, so we can see the whole picture.

Comment: But  @Inject
    public UserController(final UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;  
    } is giving error....like The blank final field dao may not have been initialized

Comment: Which error are you getting from the inject part? The stack that you presented in your question complains about missing DAO dependency, not the userService... Can you post the full class here?

Comment: Could not autowire field: private com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.dao.DAO   com.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.UserController.dao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [com.emc.bdma.itaudemo.postgres.dao.DAO] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.

Comment: Is your DAO class annotated as Component or Service? Have you tried my sollution?

Comment: could you please post the full code of these two classes (after the change)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82208/discussion-between-aman-and-smajl).